# Detail view doesn't respond to MasterViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UISplitViewController which is also a root view of UIWindow. I set two UINavigationControllers as master view controller and detail view controller respectively. A UITableViewController is a root view of UINavigationController which is inside masterviewcontroller. Detail view controller responds properly when I select a item from UITableViewController. However, detail view controller stop respond when I push an another UITableViewController from UINavigationController of MasterViewController.

I use [[splitviewcontroller.viewcontrollers lastObject] topViewController] to get its detail view controller. It works on first view controller inside UINavigation controller, but after I use self.navigationcontroler pushViewController to push a new viewcontroller,and use [[splitviewcontroller.viewcontrollers lastObject] topViewController] on this new view controller. Somehow, I cannot get this splitviewcontroller's detail view controller.

Could any specialist help me with it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[[splitviewcontroller.viewcontrollers lastObject] topViewController]` try using `[[splitviewcontroller.viewcontrollers lastObject] visibleViewController]`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems it still cannot get the view controller inside the detail view controller.

Comment: Unless the OP is presenting a modal view controller, topViewController and visibleViewController should return the same thing.

Comment: The second time I use this method from the UIViewController which is pushed from a root view controller of UINavigationController. This is UINavigation controller is the root view of Master view controller. Is this the reason why this method couldn't work?

Comment: Well you could try `[[self.splitviewcontroller.viewcontrollers lastObject] visibleViewController]` or `[[[self.splitviewcontroller.viewcontrollers lastObject] viewControllers] lastObject]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a very complex hierarchy. My suggestion would be to map out the UI structure and refer to the Storyboard for aid. You can use the parentViewController property of the View Controller to get a reference back to the desired view controller. In addition the viewControllers property will return the array of view controllers managed by the receiver so you can see how the hierarchy structure is like. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried used parentViewController, but it still cannot get what I want.